# Folder in the programdata disappeared

Tags: windows-vista

I have an application that write data in the programdata folder in vista. The application seems to write data to that location but the folder is not visible. What will be the problem for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vista virtualizes directories that you don't have access to write to (ie C:\Program Files).  So:
C:\Program Files\Your Program\Your File.txt
becomes:
C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Virtual Store\Program Files\Your Program\Your File.txt

This is a new security feature to Vista, which has a lot of benefits, but it means you'll need to do a little more to make your app work correctly with vista.

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isv/thread/43326201-94a7-4c5b-b490-20782f58cfda)

Answer (score 0):

Program Data folder is one of Vista's forbidden zones administered by Windows Resources Protection mechanisms. If you value a stable operating systems, don't play with this folder.
See [About Windows Resource Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382503%28VS.85%29.aspx).

By default this folder is hidden.

Comment: Program Data folder is like the Local Settings folder in Windows XP, it's not for deleting, it contains the settings of your installed programs. Any missed files in that directory it could lead to non-working programs.